# How to add SharePoint List as one of the data connection type in SSRS report?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services, connection

I want to create a report with SSRS that consumes data from SharePoint list. When I add a new shared data source in the Business Intelligence Studio, all the options other than the SharePoint List are displayed in the "Type" as shown below.

[image]

Please let me know is there any method to get SharePoint List as a connection type here. Please guide.

Comment: It would be great if you can let us know if you are using VS or Report builder. Can you please post a screenshot where it is grayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please create a Shared Datasource instead of "Datasource". 
I'll suggest you to read [this](http://nikpatel.net/2010/06/11/step-by-step-consuming-sharepoint-2010-lists-data-in-the-ssrs-2008-r2-reports/) step by step article, it helped me with my first report. J

Comment: This was what I was doing, but during the creation of Shared Data Source, I was unable to get the connection type as SharePoint List. Please see the edited question above.

Comment: You can select XML and give the list webservice url. http://nikpatel.net/2010/04/30/step-by-step-consuming-sharepoint-lists-data-in-the-ssrs-reports/

Comment: Is this the last alternative to access the SharePoint list data in SSRS?

Comment: Both selecting XML or Sharepoint uses webservice to fetch data. The only difference that's there is the fact that you give URL in sharepoint as a source whereas you give webservice url in XML. If you can provide me the exact details of the report builder you are using and what additional software you installed, I can try to replicate the scenario.